# Re-asking for Declined Facebook Permissions (auth_type=rerequest) does not work

Tags: php, facebook

we are developing a Facebook application with PHP SDK 3.2.3 and Javascript SDK. I need to re-ask users permission to publish on their wall if they denied access to publish on Facebook at login.

As [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading) says:

> [...] Your app must re-ask for declined permissions with special handling. [...]
>
> [...] Web apps must explicitly pass a new option to the Login Dialog: auth_type: rerequest. Details on how the new option works on the web is covered in our documentation on using the JavaScript SDK on the Web.

but we tried with this request:

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?auth_type=rerequest&client_id=1...7&redirect_uri=MY_PAGE&state=a1f4412db0617ef1a620ac1d1ebc2af8&sdk=php-sdk-3.2.3&campaign_page_with_active_panel=MY_PAGE

but users are redirected directly on MY_PAGE url and permissions are not re-requested.

This (wrong) behavior may be due to the fact that application is a test application?

Comment: What is at the facebook link ? Or does the URL include the actual code ?

Comment: This is the url we use for redirect users. We expect that with auth_type=rerequest, facebook ask again permissions, but nothing happen.

Comment: Where in the documentation did you find that you should add `auth_type=rereqeust` in the url?

Comment: The URL you have shown does not include a `scope` – so what permission do you think you are trying to “re-ask” for here exactly?

Comment: @WizKid, link is in third line of my question.

Comment: @CBroe, I've never used scope before. Can you link me documentation about scope?

Comment: `scope` is the parameter used to ask for any permissions in the first place (and is described in the general Login documentation) – so if you have never even used that, then your question about re-asking for permissions makes no sense, because you can hardly re-ask for something that you have not even asked for before already.

Comment: To be more clear about this: when the user already has accepted all permissions provided by `scope`-parameter, no dialogue appears and the user only sees some flickering before returning to the page provided by `redirect_uri`-parameter. Therefore, check first if it makes sense to show the re-request-link to the user.

Answer (score 7):

On the js sdk I directly call the login method like this:

```
FB.login( function( response ) {
      if (response.status == 'connected') {

      }
},{
      scope: 'email,public_profile',
      return_scopes: true,
      auth_type: 'rerequest'
 });
```

On the server side I use the accesstoken to request for user details on Facebook. If the email is not provided I return an error telling the user that he needs to log in again and provide email. When they click the login button again because of the **auth_type: 'rerequest'** part they will be requested again for permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that user declined email permission, with FacebookSDK and laravel where $fb is instance of FacebookSDK, you can:

```
return redirect()->to($fb->getReRequestUrl(['email']));
```

without FacebookSDK:

```
return redirect('https://www.facebook.com/v2.10/dialog/oauth?' . build_query([
                    'client_id'     => config('services.facebook.client_id'),
                    'redirect_uri'  => 'http://localhost:8000/social_auth/facebook/callback',
                    'state'         => $state,
                    'auth_type'     => 'rerequest',
                    'scope'         => 'email'
                ]));
```

Answer (score -1):

In php SDK (3.x) auth_type rerequest can be send to Facebook via getLoginUrl parameter:

```
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
    'scope' => 'public_profile, user_friends, email',
    'redirect_url' => 'http://www.yourul.com/example.php',
    'auth_type' => 'rerequest',
));
```